# What does it mean to provide an API

Tags: android, web-services, api, webserver

I cam across this question,

> Does XYZ application provide an API?

Now I am not really sure what it means to 'provide' and API.

Now let's say that I am working on an Android app and my app is going to talk to multiple users, based on actions of a single user. Now, I am going to need to host some service on the web.

User will make contact with the server and my backend services will take care of whatever is required (save stuff in Database/forward some message to someone else or anything.).

- Now I am guessing that anyone can call this service, and use it right?
- Will my backend service be called as an API?
- What do I have to do different to 'provide' an API?
- Or what do I have to do to 'prevent' access to my API?

Comment: This is a board for **Programming Questions**, not for google search

Comment: Ref. [Wiki: APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for what an API is. A client/server API (as over HTTP) is generally a Web API - but it's the same concept: "An application programming interface (API) specifies how some software components should interact with each other."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide an API means that you are providing a(n) server-side endpoint that your application, or a programmer, can hit with some sort of request (typically a HTTP request).

How you implement that is up to you. Most people these days try to provide some sort of HTTP endpoint that has a well-structured URL scheme (i.e. www.mysite.com/users/statistics) that, depending on the HTTP operation you are trying to perform, will behave differently. This is typically known as a RESTful API (what is and isn't considered RESTful is always a hot topic for debate, but it is what people *call* these types of APIs). Check out http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/ for a good intro to this.

To answers your questions directly:

1. You are able to control who can use your API, and how often they can use it.
2. Technically, yes, things hitting your backend service will be considered API calls.
3. You will need to describe your current architecture before anyone can give a decent comment as to what you will need to do to "provide" an API.
4. There are a multitude of things you can do to control access to an API - ranging from basic authentication, through to issuing API keys/tokens. Take a look at http://www.slideshare.net/rnewton/making-sense-of-api-access-control for a decent explanation.

Hope that helps!