# What Is the Opposite of "Consume an API"?

Tags: api, rest

I've heard of the concept of "sending" and "receiving" data via an API. "Consuming" data would be "receiving" the data. In terms of "consuming" data, what would be its corresponding opposite term?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to provide an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178334/what-does-it-mean-to-provide-an-api)

Comment: @pkamb No. Koen's answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps even 'exposing' an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serving

Think of it as the API as a waiter serving your meal, and you consuming it.

In this article the authors use serving as an opposite to consuming: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/